# Storing reference of a class instance member function makes it loose scope

Tags: node.js, class, scope, ecmascript-6, this

I am using Node v8.1.3

I have a class `Utility` in file `utility.js`

```
class Utility {
    constructor() {
        this.typeChecker = require('javascript-type-checker');
        this.internalErrors = require('../constants/internalErrors');
        this.axios = require('axios');
        this.config = require('../config');
    }

    getCurrentWeatherByLatLong(latitude, longitude) {
        if(!this.isValidLatitude(latitude)) throw this.internalErrors.ERR_LAT_INVALID;
        if(!this.isValidLongitude(longitude)) throw this.internalErrors.ERR_LONG_INVALID;
        const url = `${this.config.BASE_URL}?appid=${this.config.API_KEY}&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`;
        return this.axios.default.get(url);
    }

    isValidLatitude(latitude) {
        return (this.typeChecker.isNumber(latitude) && latitude >= -90 && latitude <=90);
    }

    isValidLongitude(longitude) {
        return (this.typeChecker.isNumber(longitude) && longitude >= -180 && longitude <= 180);
    }
}

module.exports = new Utility();
```

Now, in my other file, when i do

```
const utility = require('./utility');
utility.getCurrentWeatherByLatLong(Number(latitude), Number(longitude))
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
```

it works fine. However, when i do

```
const utility = require('./utility');
const functionToCall = utility.getCurrentWeatherByLatLong;
functionToCall(Number(latitude), Number(longitude))
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
```

I get the error: `Cannot read property 'isValidLatitude' of undefined`.

Why does this error occur and how can i resolve it? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function to bind the context:

```
constructor() {
    this.typeChecker = require('javascript-type-checker');
    this.internalErrors = require('../constants/internalErrors');
    this.axios = require('axios');
    this.config = require('../config');
    this.getCurrentWeatherByLatLong = this.getCurrentWeatherByLatLong.bind(this)
}
```

`this` points to the object on which the function was called. So, when you call `utility.getCurrentWeatherByLatLong(...)`, `this` is `utility`. However, when you call `functionToCall(...)`, `this` is `undefined`.

Alternatively, as you've suggested in the comments, you could bind `functionToCall` to `utility`:

```
const utility = require('./utility');
let functionToCall = utility.getCurrentWeatherByLatLong;
functionToCall = functionToCall.bind(utility);
functionToCall(Number(latitude), Number(longitude)).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Okay that worked. Why did it loose scope though? and shouldn't I have had to bind `functionToCall` to `utility`?

Comment: @AyushGupta I've updated my answer with a better explanation. Hopefully that answers your questions :)

Comment: thanks! But the thing is, when I do `functionToCall = functionToCall.bind(utility);` i get that error again

Comment: @AyushGupta hmm, that's strange. I've just tested it on a much smaller sample app and that logic seems to work. Are you getting exactly the same error as before?

Comment: sorry fr the late reply, but yeah. I'll try again though